# error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Set<ElemType>'

Tags: c++, struct

I read a half-dozen forum threads relating to this error and most were due to a string declaration and the rest were not relevant to this issue.

This error is in a program that takes on input string, compares it to a list of strings then returns the strings that are close matches. That simple explanation is the gist, the actual implementation is has a bit more to it.

In a test implementation that compiled and works, I used this line of code

```
Set<Lexicon::CorrectionT> matches = lex.suggestCorrections(line, maxDistance);
```

Set is a class (uses a bst class) I am reusing from a CS106B course and Lexicon is another class from the course that I wrote and am now reusing for an unrelated project. The function `suggestCorrections` takes a string `line` and an edit distance to then compare the string and returns a `Set` of suggestions.

I revised the line to this

```
matchSet.corrections = lex.suggestCorrections(matchSet);
```

by defining a `CorrectionT` corrections within a `Lexicon::MatchesT matchSet` and defining `matchSet` in a preceding function and then passing it as a reference. `MatchesT` contains the fields for `line` and  `maxDistance`.

From my knowledge these two lines of code are identical with the exception of the approach I am using.

So, why do I get this error "error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Set'"

Comment: What is the exact type of `matchSet.corrections`?

Comment: CorrectionT - @Matteo Italia has it correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From my knowledge these two lines of code are identical with the exception of approach I am using.

Nope, they are completely different; one instantiates a new object, calling the copy constructor of `Set<Lexicon::CorrectionT>`; the other copies the object on the right to the (already created) object on the left, calling the assignment operator, which, for some reason, isn't available.

Has it been implemented in `Set<>`? What type is `matchSet.corrections` and what return type has `suggestCorrections`?

Comment: as I wrote the question that became apparent. On the left is a Set<typename element type> and on the right is a struct